# jQuery Mobile - synchronize checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I am trying to synchronize two `checkboxes` one from  `Landscape view` and another for `Portrait view`

I am using jquery mobile and `HTML 5`, is there any way to do it without using jquery code ?

Strangelly it works if we have inputs with the same id, what I know is not correct. 
With two labels and one input the design of the first option looks strange.

Please, find the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/titombo/o7akzqps/).

Comment: Why do you not want to use jQuery code? You have jQuery and jQuery Mobile already included in your project and it is a very simple to handle the change events of the 2 checkboxes.

Comment: @ezanker, but as far as I know it doesn't synchronize automatically. If it does, let me know please. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is automatic synchronization, however it is pretty easy to do with jQuery:

```
<div class="portrait">            
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chk-p" />Check me</label>
</div>       
<div class="landscape">            
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chk-l" />Check me</label>
</div>
```

Given the 2 checkboxes, handle the change event on each one and update the other:

```
$("#chk-p").on("change", function(e){
     $("#chk-l").prop("checked", this.checked).checkboxradio("refresh");
});

$("#chk-l").on("change", function(e){
    $("#chk-p").prop("checked", this.checked).checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

Make sure and call .checkboxradio("refresh") after changing checkbox value in order to update the jQM widget.

> **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/o7akzqps/3/)**